# Are regular expressions with C++ that specific?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am sorry this resembles to homework. But, I have just been unable to parse days, months and years using std::regex. I just can't see what is missing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<regex>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> series;
    series.push_back("2013-02-01,54.87,55.20,54.67,54.92,2347600,54.92");
    series.push_back("2013-01-31,54.74,54.97,53.99,54.29,3343300,54.29");
    series.push_back("2013-01-30,54.84,55.35,54.68,54.68,2472800,54.68");

    const std::regex date("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})");
    std::smatch dates;

    for (unsigned int  i = 0; i < series.size() ; i++)
    {
        if (std::regex_match(series[i], dates, date))
            std::cout << dates[1] << "\t" << dates[2] << "\t" << dates[3] << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "No match!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the code do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Have you got a question or you are just sharing

Comment: What do you mean by "that specific"? What problems are you seeing with what you have? What would you like us to do, other than just doing your homework for you?

Comment: Are you using g++? Yeah, regex don’t work there.

Comment: Read the documentation on [`regex_match`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/).  I would in particular compare it against the functions in the "see also" list.  Second, @KonradRudolph's comment is good advise: some person of questionable taste checked in a `regex` library that has nothing but stub implementations to at least one version of g++.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. I expect the code picks up one string of the series std::vector after another, and for each string extracts the year and assigns it to dates[1], the month to dates[2] and the day to dates[3] . But the regex as it is now doesn't work, it seems. I am returned "No match!".

Comment: @edouard You still haven't mentioned what compiler, version etc. As others have mentioned, if you're using GCC, regex doesn't work. Your (only?) other option is to use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, use `regex_search`, not `regex_match`. `regex_match` requires that the regular expression match the **entire** target text; `regex_search` finds whatever part of the target text matches. Or you could change the regular expression to end with a ".*" to swallow the rest of the target text.

Comment: Not very C++ specific, is it? :)